# need help adding a random color to my random lines in java using Math.random

Tags: java, eclipse, random

the lines need to have a random color added to them. I know that I have the basis down as far as coloring the lines go but when i run the applet, the lines remain black. Its probably a simple mistake but I'm a newbie so please help!

```
    int random = (int)Math.random();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) 
    {
        int R = (int)(Math.random() * 255);
        int G = (int)(Math.random() * 255);
        int B = (int)(Math.random() * 255);

        Color c = newColor(R,G,B);
        g.setColor(c); 

        int x1 = (int)(Math.random() *  400) + 10;
        int y1 = (int)(Math.random() *  300) + 10;
        int x2 = (int)(Math.random() * 400) + 10;
        int y2 = (int)(Math.random() * 300) + 10;

        g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2); 

    }
```

Comment: I copied this directly into a test app and it worked. What are you running this with?

Comment: And what method is this code in?

Comment: I'm running it in eclipse, the lines had color?

Comment: I ran it in Eclipse in a simple Swing app (`JFrame` with `JPanel` that had a `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method.